# How to crop specific area of image using circle or rectangle using python CV2?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I am working on a simple app where my task is to crop some specific area in that image when I show my image on canvas then after I select the button which will be used to crop by circle or rectangle. The main task is to **count cells** in some specific microscopic slides in our lab.
I am a beginner and have not that much experience. I need your help :).

Our target is to remove the background using the cropping method using a circle or rectangle.
I had already used someone's code where I can crop the are by rectangle but for now, I also want to add a specific portion to the code for circle but I couldn't find any solution. I just found only how to draw the circle for now.

**Target:**
I want a function that can just get an input image and its argument that how it will be cropped either `Circle` or by `Rectangle`.
Code for Rectangle.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib



import cv2 
cropping = False

x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0

image = cv2.imread('bac.jpg')
oriImage = image.copy()


def mouse_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
        cropping = True

    # Mouse is Moving
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if cropping == True:
            x_end, y_end = x, y

    # if the left mouse button was released
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # record the ending (x, y) coordinates
        x_end, y_end = x, y
        cropping = False # cropping is finished

        refPoint = [(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)]

        if len(refPoint) == 2: #when two points were found
            roi = oriImage[refPoint[0][1]:refPoint[1][1], refPoint[0][0]:refPoint[1][0]]
            cv2.imwrite('crop_image.png', roi)
            cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)


cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", mouse_crop)

while True:

    i = image.copy()

    if not cropping:
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

    elif cropping:
        cv2.rectangle(i, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", i)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @nathancy thank you for the link but these are finding the rectangular regions of interest which is not my target for now. above code is working fine for now which can crop the image and get back the cropped image but I want the same function for circle too.

Comment: To search in the right direction, remember that an image is an array and you can't have an array that has a different number of cols. However, you can have an array of zeros where the values outside the circle aren't needed. I believe you should implement this only if the images will be used as profile pictures. :)

Comment: thank you for your consideration. implemented by using the open-source method written in this repo.
[Link](https://github.com/chiang9/polygon_crop)
you will just do `img_crop(img_array)`